# PHP site stopped working after Ubuntu upgrade -- no longer processing <? directives

Tags: php

I run a small PHP site for my parents on AWS. After upgrading the host from Ubuntu Server 13.04 to 13.10 (in order to patch the Heartbleed bug in OpenSSL) the site has stopped working.

My PHP knowledge is minimal.

One problem seems to be that the code uses `<?` ... `?>` escaping instead of  `<?php` ... `?>`. The PHP code between those tags is now being returned in the HTML rather than being processed.

The upgrade [apparently](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5) changed the version of the `php5` package from 5.4.9 to 5.5.3.

Is there a way to run PHP in a compatibility mode? Is there a good reason for this breaking change? Or is something else going on that I don't know about?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: There is a an option for this in php config file, afaik

Comment: Seems like that upgrade replaced your php.ini file which it should never do. Check if you have some old version around and compare the differences.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why you should never rely on short open tags

Comment: Short tags have been discouraged for many, many, many years and this is precisely the reason. Why have you been using them despite that prevalent advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it might have done something to your `php.ini` file. Look for `short-open-tag` and make sure it's turned `On`. Also, make sure it didn't append a second one somewhere further down the file (I've sometimes seen config settings added more than once to config files).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the problem.

Comment: -1: No, that's bad advice. There is a reason we have discouraged short open tags for the last decade or so. This is it. Instead fix the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for your concern, but this site just needs to run now. I prefer to spend my time working on other things at the moment, and changing the tag style throughout the code would only satisfy the OCD in me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While it might not be good coding practice, it's also outside the scope of the question. That question has [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity: It's _absolutely_ within the scope of the question. Bad advice is bad advice no matter which question you're answering. You can't abstract that away.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: That's fine; I won't sue you for doing it. But as general advice -- recall that questions are supposed to benefit _everybody_ and are not just about your specific needs -- this is bad.

Comment: The merit of a piece of advice is ultimately up to the recipient to decide. Rather than polarising the issue and claiming something is good or bad, it's more constructive to illuminate both sides so that both OP and other readers have enough information available to make a good decision themselves.

Answer (score -2):

Open php.ini and find the below section:

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Change it to

```
   short_open_tag
   Default Value: On
   Development Value: On
   Production Value: On
```

Comment: No, don't... Instead, stop using short open tags.

Comment: I think you were downvoted primarily because you have uncommented lines which were there for humans. Only the first line is an actual configuration directive. Further, the section you show is from an introductory header, and (in my file at least) the actual config value is set lower down. So if I uncommented the line you suggest, it would have no effect.